# Next.js renders element twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

On the first image you can see next.js rendered this element twice

I used tables and thought that it is because of them but then I tried to remove tables and put jut  and it still renders twice so I don't know what it can be.

Next.js does not renders only that element but the first from this object

```
const Sections = {
  1: Locations,
  0: Departments, // here it will render this one twice
  2: Managers,
  3: JobTitles,
};
```

Maybe it has something to do with useState and my statemanagment in this code below

Component that renders twice.

```
const Locations = () => {
  return <div>hdjsad</div>;
};
```

[image]

[image]

```
// Tab Sections
import Locations from ''
import Departments from ''
import Managers from ''
import JobTitles from ''

import Icons from "../../Icons";
import TabItem from "./TabItem";

const tabs_text = ["Locations", "Departments", "Managers", "Job Titles"];

const Sections = {
  0: Locations, // THIS IS THE COMPONENT WHICH RENDERS TWICE
  1: Departments,
  2: Managers,
  3: JobTitles,
};

const SettingsTab = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState<number>(0);

  const select = useCallback((id: number) => {
    return () => setActive(id);
  }, []);

  const ActiveSection = useMemo(() => Sections[active], [active]);

  return (
    <section className={"mb-[24px]"}>
      <header
        className={"w-full flex items-center mb-[34px] pl-[24px] pr-[12px]"}
      >
        <div className={"flex space-x-[8px] !mb-0 overflow-x-scroll"}>
          {tabs_text.map((tab_text, i) => {
            return (
              <div onClick={select(i)} key={i}>
                <TabItem active={+active === i}>{tab_text}</TabItem>
              </div>
             
            );
          })}
        </div>

        <ImportLocationsAndFilter />
      </header>

      <ActiveSection />
      
    </section>
  );
};
```

**APP.js**

```
import { AppProps } from "next/app";

import "antd/dist/antd.css";

import "../styles/global.css";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: I am not sure why it renders `Location` twice, but there is an error in your onClick handler. `onClick` should be a function, i.e. `onClick={() => select(i)}`. Other wise your select function is called immediatly upon rendering.

Comment: @Araelath inside of select function I return another function so it is okay

Comment: Ha you right, I see that now! `useCallback` is usually not used that way, I am not sure why you need a constant reference to your `select` function. `select` will still return a different function each time it is called. It's probably unrelated to your problem though

Comment: @Araelath isn't it a bad idea to use () => select() since it also creates new function every time?

Comment: It does create a new function every time, however you're passing it to a `div`, so it will not cause any re-render. Even so, you only really need to worry about constant reference to function in case you have a very expensive render function, or you need a stable reference for use  in a useEffect dependencies array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just imported my tabs dynamically and set SSR: false.

It has to do something with next.js hydration.

https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import

```
dynamic(
  () => import(""),
  {
    ssr: false,
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet so I'll do it here. I know react says in the official docs to never rely on UseMemo or Use callback for functionality. It says you should create your application so it works without them, and then add them for performance reasons. What would happen if you took the useMemo out and put

```
ActiveSelection = Selections[active]
```

I don't think it'll fix your problem but it might give you more insight into what's causing it.

Answer (score 0):

In this case re-installing `pnpm` was helpful for us.

We were using `pnpm` on the project, and this issue was happening on only one system (windows).

Uninstall and re-installing `pnpm` using `npm` solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

It's strange behaviour / bug related to next.js ssr to fix it wrap your Component in a div like this:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return <div id=#root><Component {...pageProps} /></div>;
}
```